# how to get the coordinates x, y into a div ID?

Tags: javascript, html, css, coordinates

Hell i would like to get x , y coordinates into div ID ,at the moment when i click everywhere on the page i get **X coords:193,Y coords:53** under the divs i created in HTML.

This is my Code in :

```
       function show_coords(event)
           {
        var  x =event.clientX;
        var y=event.clientY;
        $("#click").html("X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y);
        return false;
        }

        <body onmousedown="show_coords(event)">
            <div id="x">x</div>
            <div id="y">y</div>
            <div id="click"></div>

             </body>
```

i want  x coords:193 to go inside #x and y coords:53 to go inside #y.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#x").text(x);
$("#y").text(y);
```

You can just put that before `return false` in `show_coords`

Since you're already using jQuery, instead of doing `onmousedown` you can just do:

```
$("body").on("mousedown", show_coords)
```